# Ionic blank screen on pause/resume

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Similar issue has been asked for several times:

[PhoneGap/Cordova blank screen on pause/resume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170592/phonegap-cordova-blank-screen-on-pause-resume)

[AdMob with PhoneGap 3.0 on resume displays blank page until screen is touched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508049/admob-with-phonegap-3-0-on-resume-displays-blank-page-until-screen-is-touched)

**Description:**

Sometimes, after the app is suspended (by pressing "home" for example), when it's launched again the browser viewport is blank. As soon as you touch inside the web view it renders the page correctly. This issue can reproduce in an old android device with low performance.

**Workaroud:**

Workaroud is provided in the two Questions, they listen to the 'resume' event and make some change on the UI to make the UI refresh. I have not tried, but I think it should be able to work, but this is so dirty. Anyone can provide a elegant solution?

Comment: Can you name a low performance device and android version where this happens? and when you say "sometimes", does it mean it sometimes works properly and sometimes the issue happens on the same device?

Comment: Android version 4.3. Yes, sometimes works properly and sometimes the issue happens on the same device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried maybe implementing `$scope.$apply()` call if the device is running on old version of android.

Is there a reason you are wanting to support these old devices? Most App's have stopped supporting devices any older than Android 4.0.3 as they are known to have a-lot of bugs, and the market share for those devices is rather minimal these days.

See the android market share stats below:
http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: Android version 4.3, but the device's performance is low. What's your meaning by mentioning "implementing $scope.$apply()"?